# Unity3d integration to Eclipse. Where is the error?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I read lots of guide about Unity integration Eclipse. But i have a some problem here. I did all steps guide.

This is reference page = [Unity Form](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse)

My Programs these;

- Windows 8
- Eclipse Android Developer Tools Build: v22.0.1-685705
- Unity Version 4.1.3f3 (Free Verison)
- (Eclipse, configured for usage with Android. Also i have SDK and NDK for Eclipse)

There has been no problem so far.

This is my way; **Please check this images for progress;**

**[Please Click This for showing progressing images](http://po.st/3YTiW1)**

This is last step's error message;
"Android library project s cannot be launched"

How can i solve this problem? Any idea?

**Main Java Class here;**

```
package com.thecodemakerz.cube;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity   {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

**Java Class' Android Manifest is here;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" package="com.thecodemakerz.cube" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
</manifest>
```

**UnityLibrary Project's and UnityJava Project has an same Android Manifest**.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps that i did for the integration. The difference is that i'm exporting the UnityLibrary as a Jar, and then using in my project.

1. Do all you did until the selection of Unity project in Eclipse as a library.
2. Instead of that, export the project as jar file. When exporting, remove AndroidManifest.xml (on root folder) and libs folder (where're libmono, libunit and classes.jar)
3. Now go to your libs folder in your Android Aplication Project. Add in this folder all the contents of libs folder from Unity exported project (where're libunit, libmono and classes.jar). Add in this folder your exported jar file too.
4. Now you can extend your Activity like you did before. Everything should work.

And don't forget to look, and post, your LogCat, if you encounter more problems.